# how does OOP version of a custom tensorflow model work

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi guys i have a question from object oriented implementation of a tensorflow model  that i see in CS231.n and this is the model:

```
class TwoLayerFC(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super().__init__()        
        initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(scale=2.0)
        self.fc1 = tf.layers.Dense(hidden_size, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=initializer)
        self.fc2 = tf.layers.Dense(num_classes,
                               kernel_initializer=initializer)
    def call(self, x, training=None):
        x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

and this is the function that test it:

```
def test_TwoLayerFC():
    model = TwoLayerFC(hidden_size, num_classes)
    with tf.device(device):
        x = tf.zeros((64, input_size))
        scores = model(x)

# Now that our computational graph has been defined we can run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    scores_np = sess.run(scores)
    print(scores_np.shape)
```

my question is how does model is being called with the input x and scores is made, i mean this isn't pythonic way of calling an object function and it should be:

```
model.call(x)
```

or the call method should be a magic method call i mean:

```
def __call__(self, x, training=None)
```

Comment: I think it is the limitation of Tensorflow caused the problem. You have to understand that Tensorflow is kind of static. The `call()` method actually is a part of model generator but not the executor when you run the model. Or say, `call()` 
 only defines computation rules and is only called when `model = TwoLayerFC(hidden_size, num_classes)` runs. p.s: I am not familiar with Keras but I believe it is a wrapper upon tf because of `tf.keras.Model`.

Comment: So you say it's the way of tensorflow OOP version works and it doesn't relate to how python works?